# Kendo TimePicker in a Grid: How Do I Get the Value?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following time picker in a Kendo grid:

```
 columns.Bound(s => s.StartTime).Title("Start Time").Width(76).ClientTemplate((
    @Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
        .Name("StartTimePicker" + "#=ID#")
        .Format("HH:mm:ss")
        .Interval(15)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value: StartTime" })
        .ToClientTemplate()).ToHtmlString());
```

This works as intended. I also have the following button in the grid:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Save").Text("<span class=\"k-icon k-i-check\"></span>Save").Click("saveSchedule")).Width(80).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-center" });
```

I want to access the value of the time picker in my saveSchedule function, which is:

```
function saveSchedule(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

       // etc

       // need code to get time here
```

How do I get the time that was selected in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my saveSchedule function:

```
var timepicker = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').find('.k-input');
schedule.StartTime = timepicker[0].value;
```

Solved the issue.